# How to receive data without any garbled message?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Recently,I have a project to receive data from an ECG device to Raspberry Pi 3.
Here is my code

```
import serial
import time

port=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0",baudrate=19200,timeout=0.5)

while True:
     rcv=port.read()
     print (rcv)
```

The result of the code are garbled messages.Then,I use the following code

```
import serial
import time

port=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0",baudrate=19200,timeout=0.5)

while True:
     rcv=port.read()
     print (rcv.decode('utf-8'))
```

It still gets so many garbled messages.Could anyone help me to solve this question? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you share an example of the garbled message?

Comment: Can you post some examples of these garbled messages, and the messages you expect to receive? Are you certain that _all_ the serial port settings are correct for your device?

Comment: I expect to receive the data from ECG device.And the correct result should to be values.

Comment: I confirm that the baudrate is correct.

Comment: This is what it receives from my ECG device. It looks like → �vysptvnltxtu�vnr�uruvhch���h2syp����zyzrpoqnpnrtwvvz�t‌​pstruuprwvpqpw�zqvxr‌​qtrtvtuutpsuwrtstwzq‌​ou�xrnqvxwtuvumnt{ut‌​txtsswwxui�J

Comment: Try experimenting with parity and/or stopbits. Or the 7/8 bits setting